# Wrap updates on screen, ListView and GridView do not. Why?

Tags: listview, flutter, gridview

## My app

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Grid())));

class Grid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridState createState() => _GridState();
}

class _GridState extends State<Grid> {

  List<Widget> pieces = [Text('a'), Text('b'), Text('c')];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => setState(() => pieces[0] = Text('*')),
        child: Wrap(children: pieces),
        // child: ListView(children: pieces),
        // child: GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 3, children: pieces),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## The Problem

After I tap the Wrap, a' changes into '*' on screen - as expected

When I replace the Wrap with either the ListView or the GridView, 'a' does not change. Why ?

Same behaviour on both 'stable' and 'master'

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.18.0-5.0.pre.89, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

## Keys seem not to help

Someone posted and suggested to use keys - but deleted the post before I could thank them. Using keys like this ...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Grid())));

class Grid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridState createState() => _GridState();
}

class _GridState extends State<Grid> {

  List<Widget> pieces = [Text('a', key:UniqueKey()), Text('b', key:UniqueKey()), Text('c', key:UniqueKey())];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => setState(() => pieces[0] = Text('*', key:UniqueKey())),
        child: Wrap(children: pieces),
        // child: ListView(children: pieces),
        // child: GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 3, children: pieces),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

... makes no difference.

## Because Wrap is very different ?

According to the Flutter documentation the inheritance is:

- Object Diagnosticable DiagnosticableTree Widget RenderObjectWidget MultiChildRenderObjectWidget **Wrap**
- Object Diagnosticable DiagnosticableTree Widget StatelessWidget ScrollView BoxScrollView **ListView**
- Object Diagnosticable DiagnosticableTree Widget StatelessWidget ScrollView BoxScrollView **GridView**

So ListView and GridView are both very different from Wrap. Can this explain the problem ? If so, how to solve it ?

Comment: it was my first answer but now I think the reason is in GridView.count constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add an unique `key` property to GridView like this

```
GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 3, children: pieces, key: UniqueKey());
```

or use `GridView.builder` constructor elsewhere

```
child: GridView.builder(
  itemCount: 3,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => pieces[index],
),
```

Comment: Thank you, @GenchiGenbutsu, so much. Yes, both ways work. Now I just need to understand why ;-) I'm still quite a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

try using the `ValueListenableBuilder<T> class`.
it can **reRender** where you exactly want without rebuilding the whole widget tree that would be great if you are using expensive widgets in your current page.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title')
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('You're list should be generating below :'),
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget child) {
                // This builder will only get called when the index
                // is updated.
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('pieces[index]'),
                    child,
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: _counter,
              // The child parameter is most helpful if the child is
              // expensive to build and does not depend on the value from
              // the notifier.
              child: expensiveWidget,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
        onPressed: () => index++,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can also see the full docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Taba, for suggesting a solution so soon. I'm afraid though I'll need some time to see how to apply and check if it works. I'm quite a beginner still.